# django.setup method messes with logging

Tags: python, django, error-logging

I am writing an independent script file in django that will be run from command line. This is not a management command in django. But I still need to import django models

if i do

```
django.setup()
```

then

```
logging.info("message")
```

does the logging on the terminal rather than on the file specified.

If I remove django.setup() logging works fine.

Why is this happening and is there a workaround for this.

Note: Django Version is 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Though django.setup() was the issue. Adding a filehandler to the logging class has fixed the issue

How,

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'jade.settings')
import django
django.setup()

fh = logging.FileHandler('/home/jadeuser/workspace/jade/src/script/event_load.log')
logger1 = logging.getLogger('event_load.addcard')
logger1.addHandler(fh)
logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger1.info("this will be written to a file irrespective of having django.setup().")
```

Hope this helps, anyone in the future.